# What is the best way to implement security for critical Android application consuming JSON and XML

Tags: android, xml, json, web-services, security

I am developing an Android application which consumes confidential data from a web service which I have exposed. The webservice serves both Json and XML. What is the best way to implement security for this application ? I have looked through a few options suchas SSL and OAuth but still confused in making the pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you comparing oAuth with SSL?

- **OAuth:** OAuth is an open standard for authorization. OAuth provides a method for clients to access server resources on behalf of a resource owner (such as a different client or an end-user). 
  Typical use: Using Facebook or Google account to access other websites.
- **SSL**: Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), are cryptographic protocols that provide communication security over the Internet.

So if you want to consume/expose secure data then you would publish your webservices over **HTTPS** only, which basically uses SSL/TLS internally to communicate to server.

As you mentioned you need to consume confidential data then I would suggest you use SOAP webservices, instead of RESTful webservices. Both SOAP and Restful webservices support transfer of XML and JSON data but SOAP should be used where security and confidentiality is primary concern.